# Не могу запустить примеры на Vulkan в visual studio

Tags: visual-c++, vulkan

Хотел запустить примеры на Vulkan из репозитория LunarG Vulkan Samples GitHub(https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples).
Ошибка      CMake Error at Repos\VulkanSamples\CMakeLists.txt:200 (message):
  Must define location of glslang binaries -- see BUILD.md  VULKAN_SAMPLES

В Инструкции по сборке было так(оригинал:https://github.com/LunarG/VulkanSamples/blob/master/BUILD.md)
glslang
This repository has a required dependency on the glslang repository. The glslang repository is required because it contains components that are required to build the samples. You must clone the glslang repository and build its install target. Follow the build instructions in the glslang README.md file. Ensure that the update_glslang_sources.py script has been run as part of building glslang. You must also take note of the glslang install directory and pass it on the CMake command line for building this repository, as described below.

Comment: не по теме - просто интересно зачем вам он? :)

Comment: в приведенной Вами ссылке есть подробная инструкция по установке, прочитайте внимательней параграф про зависимости, особенно раздел `Building Dependent Repositories with Known-Good Revisions`